# three conditions in case

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

i have 2 condition in CASE WHEN, but the result is not i want

here is my code :

```
SELECT CASE WHEN count(b.id_canteen) < 2 and status = 'Active' THEN 'Available'
            ELSE 'Full' END as quota, 
       a.id_canteen, 
       name_canteen, 
       count(b.id_counter) as total 
from canteen_A a 
     join canteen_B b  on a.id_canteen=b.id_canteen 
group by a.id_canteen,
         name_canteen,
         status;
```

and this is the result

```
=================================================
|   quota   | id_canteen | name_canteen | total |
=================================================
| Available | Canteen01   | Canteen A   |   1   |
| Available | Canteen02   | Canteen B   |   1   |
| Full      | Canteen01   | Canteen A   |   1   |
=================================================
```

and the result that i want like this

```
=================================================
|   quota   | id_canteen | name_canteen | total |
=================================================
| Available | Canteen01   | Canteen A   |   2   |
| Available | Canteen02   | Canteen B   |   1   |
=================================================
```

this is field status

```
==============================
|   Status   |  id_canteen   |
==============================
| Not Active |   Canteen01   |
|   Active   |   Canteen01   |
|   Active   |   Canteen02   |
==============================
```

update:
i want add condition count(status) active < 2 . what should i do?

Comment: You are grouping by Status and not displaying it. Try including it on your select column list and you will see why you see 3 records. I believe you want a conditional count (`COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'active' THEN 1 END)`) rather than grouping by status, but I'm guessing here.

Comment: What's the logic behind going from 3 to 2 records in your expected output?  This is not clear to me.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  For instance, where does `status` come from?

Comment: @GordonLinoff status come from table canteen_B with value this
| Not Active |   Canteen01 |
|   Active     |   Canteen01  |
|   Active    |   Canteen02   |
==============================

Comment: @EzLo if i remove grouping status, it will error because its not contain in either an aggregate function or the group by clause

Comment: @MuhammadAliefAgusta that's why I mentioned the `COUNT(...)` with the status in it. Count is an aggregate function. If you could explain the logic behind your desired quota result, then it would be very clear to fix your query.

Comment: sorry sir i forgot something, i've add update in question

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `GROUP BY`.  You don't want `status` in it.  So, I think:

```
select (case when count(b.id_canteen) < 2 and
                  sum(case when status = 'Active' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
             then 'Available' 
             else 'Full' 
         end) as quota, 
       a.id_canteen, name_canteen, 
       count(b.id_counter) as total 
from canteen_A a join
     canteen_B b 
     on a.id_canteen = b.id_canteen 
group by a.id_canteen, name_canteen
```

Answer (score 0):

what does this return?

```
SELECT
      X.id_canteen, 
      X.name_canteen, 
      CASE
        WHEN X.total < 2 AND X.status = 'Active' THEN
          'Available'
        ELSE
          'Full'
      END quota
FROM
      (
        SELECT
              a.id_canteen, 
              a.name_canteen,
              b.status
              COUNT(b.id_counter) total 
          FROM
              canteen_A a 
            JOIN
              canteen_B b
                ON a.id_canteen = b.id_canteen
          GROUP BY
              a.id_canteen,
              a.name_canteen,
              b.status
        ) X
```

Comment: @MuhammadAliefAgusta, what about just the sub-query?